# Representation for idempotent semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, semigroups, idempotents

I have a semi-ring whose multiplication is non-commutative, and addition is idempotent.  That is, $ab \neq ba$ and $a + a = a$.

The semi-ring is freely generated from a finite set $\Sigma$, the semi-ring itself would be of infinite rank.

We can also assume $\times$ distributes into $+$ from the left (or right, doesn't matter).  There are also the usual identity elements 0 and 1.

How may I construct matrix representations for it?  What would be the constraints for those matrices?  Can someone give a simple example?

Comment: What other information do you have about the semiring?  You certainly can't construct a matrix representation just from what you have given.

Comment: Do I need to say that multiplication distributes into addition (from both sides), and that there are 0 and 1 as identity elements of + and $\times$ respectively?

Comment: Aren't those things part of the definition of a semiring?  So are the only facts you know about your structure that it is a semiring with non-commutative addition and idempotent multiplication?  In that case I suppose you can abstractly say something about a matrix representation for it, but you of course can't explicitly construct one, since you don't actually have an explicit object to start with.

Comment: But I don't understand if the matrix addition and multiplication would correspond to the same operations on the semi-ring.  Seems that at least addition would be different?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correspond to'?  In some sense you certainly want them to correspond, since you want a representation of your semiring.

Comment: I forgot to say the semi-ring would be generated by a finite set of elements $\in \Sigma$, but it is "free" so it is infinite.

I imagine that with the representation, each element $\in \Sigma$ of the semi-ring would be represented by a matrix, and their products in the semi-ring represented by matrix products.  But the sum in the semi-ring cannot be represented by matrix sums because matrix addition is not idempotent.  That's my problem ... maybe I've misunderstood representation theory...?

Comment: I recommend editing your question to include the information from your last comment.  Are you wanting your matrices to be over a field, or at least a ring?  In that case you indeed can't have idempotent matrix addition.

Comment: I guess if we just consider the idempotent monoid, it can be represented by projection matrices since projection is idempotent.  But this idea when *combined* with the multiplication monoid, doesn't work.  Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: The matrices are over a field, I guess that makes things simpler?  Or would matrices with semi-ring entries help solve the problem?

Comment: Well, I found a paper on the net: "Representations of near semirings and approximation of their categories" by Krishna and Chatterjee 2007.  They define the semi-ring as a semi-group with the multiplicative structure on top of it.  Then a homomorphism is a map that preserves both + and $\times$.  I've only read the beginning of the paper...

Comment: I doubt you want to allow the matrix entries to be from a semiring.  Otherwise the trivial representation by $1\times 1$ matrices would work. =]

Comment: Tara: you may look at my draft paper to see why I'm asking this:
[https://genifer.googlecode.com/files/logica-universalis%2823-Mar-2013%29.pdf]
I'm working on algebraic logic applied to natural language understanding =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is possible to find a matrix representation but since there was no answer for over a year, let me just mention two possibly useful facts.

Let $A$ be a finite set. Then the free idempotent semiring generated by $A$ appears to be $\mathbb{B}\langle A\rangle$, the set of non-commutative polynomials (with variables in $A$) over the Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B}$. Equivalently, it is the semiring of finite languages over the alphabet $A$.

Now, there is a well-known embedding of the free monoid $A^*$ into the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ and determinant $1$, given by
$$
a \to \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \qquad b \to \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
That being said, I don't see how to extend this embedding to $\mathbb{B}\langle A\rangle$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What is meant by the boolean semi-ring $\mathbb{B}$?

Comment: Also, is your example of free monoid A* generated by only 2 elements, $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Right, but you can in turn embed any free monoid with a countable basis $B = \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ by sending $a_k$ to $a^kb$.

Comment: PS:  I found this definition:  an associative ring R (maybe without identity) is called a Boolean ring if each of its element $a \in R$ is an idempotent, ie, $a^2 = a$.